# Servant API type level routing with typeclasses - howto select instance on choice (:<|>)?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out a way for picking a server handler function in a Servant API specification by specifying it's URL type. This is different from Servant.Util.Links - in that I don't want the link in text form, but select a handler function by a typelevel link.

So I have the API and an Endpoint in the API (similar to Servant.Util.Links). Now I want to "walk" through the API, picking up the server handler function matching EndPoint. This is what I came up with:

http://lpaste.net/158062

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Gonimo.GetEndpoint where


import GHC.TypeLits
import Servant.API
import Servant.Utils.Links
import Data.Proxy
import Servant.Server

class GetEndpoint api endpoint where
  getEndpoint :: Proxy m -> Proxy api -> Proxy endpoint -> ServerT api m -> ServerT endpoint m


instance (GetEndpoint b1 endpoint)  => GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint where
  getEndpoint pM _ pE (lS :<|> _) = getEndpoint pM (Proxy :: Proxy b1) pE lS


instance (GetEndpoint b2 endpoint)  => GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint where
  getEndpoint pM _ pE (_ :<|> lR) = getEndpoint pM (Proxy :: Proxy b1) pE lR
```

but ghc complains about duplicate instances:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance forall (k :: BOX) b1 b2 (endpoint :: k).
           GetEndpoint b1 endpoint =>
           GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint
    -- Defined at src/Gonimo/GetEndpoint.hs:22:10
  instance forall (k :: BOX) b1 b2 (endpoint :: k).
           GetEndpoint b2 endpoint =>
           GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint
    -- Defined at src/Gonimo/GetEndpoint.hs:26:10
```

Which I partly understand - but how else should I pick the right or the left route of :<|> at the type level?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Just in case someone tries to find a completely working solution right now - I would be really happy about even the smallest pointer in the right direction, so if you have anything useful - please just leave a comment :-)

Closed type families perhaps? The constraints package? I am still missing a link, this is pretty new ground for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish, how is it different than what `Servant.Util.Links` implements? Anyways, your problem is type class selection doesn't consider the context of an instance, so there is no way to every distinguish those instances. Instead you should compute e.g. a boolean value indicating if the endpoint is in the API, and then `e` is in `x :<|> y` if `e` is in `x` or `e` is in `y` - you will need a type level `or` function here as well. Consider `class GetEndpoint a e (r :: Bool) | a e -> r` or `type family GetEndpoint a e :: Bool`.

Comment: Thank you - I will look into those suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you user2407038 that did the trick, the following code actually compiles!

The trick as user2407038 suggested, is to use a type level bool - which gets calculated by IsElem. This way we can get the constraint into the type parameters and can select an instance based on the value of our bool -yeah!

Some boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
module Lib where


import GHC.TypeLits
import Servant.API hiding (IsElem)
import Servant.Utils.Links hiding (IsElem, Or)
import Data.Proxy
import Servant.Server
import           GHC.Exts              (Constraint)
import Network.Wai (Application)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (ExceptT)
```

We need an Or and an And at the type level:

```
type family Or (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool where
  Or 'False 'False = 'False
  Or 'False 'True = 'True
  Or 'True 'False = 'True
  Or 'True 'True = 'True

type family And (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool where
  And 'False 'False = 'False
  And 'False 'True = 'False
  And 'True 'False = 'False
  And 'True 'True = 'True

type family Not (a :: Bool) :: Bool where
  Not 'False = 'True
  Not 'True = 'False
```

-- Calculate our bool:

```
type family IsElem endpoint api :: Bool where
    IsElem e (sa :<|> sb)                   = Or (IsElem e sa) (IsElem e sb)
    IsElem (e :> sa) (e :> sb)              = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem sa (Header sym x :> sb)          = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem sa (ReqBody y x :> sb)           = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem (Capture z y :> sa) (Capture x y :> sb)
                                            = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem sa (QueryParam x y :> sb)        = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem sa (QueryParams x y :> sb)       = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem sa (QueryFlag x :> sb)           = IsElem sa sb
    IsElem (Verb m s ct typ) (Verb m s ct' typ)
                                            = IsSubList ct ct'
    IsElem e e                              = True
    IsElem sa sb                            = False

type family IsSubList a b :: Bool where
    IsSubList '[] b          = True
    IsSubList (x ': xs) y    = Elem x y `And` IsSubList xs y

type family Elem e es :: Bool where
    Elem x (x ': xs) = True
    Elem y (x ': xs) = Elem y xs
    Elem y '[] = False

type family EnableConstraint (c :: Constraint) (enable :: Bool)  :: Constraint where
     EnableConstraint c 'True = c
     EnableConstraint c 'False = ()
```

Use our IsElem to figure out whether to take the right or the left branch:

```
type family PickLeftRight endpoint api :: Bool where
  PickLeftRight endpoint (sa :<|> sb) = IsElem endpoint sb
  PickLeftRight endpoint sa = 'True
```

Our entry point:

```
-- | Select a handler from an API by specifying a type level link.
callHandler :: forall api endpoint. (GetEndpoint api endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint api))
            => Proxy api
            -> ServerT api (ExceptT ServantErr IO)
            -> Proxy endpoint
            -> ServerT endpoint (ExceptT ServantErr IO)
callHandler pA handlers pE = getEndpoint (Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint api)) pM pA pE handlers
  where
    pM = Proxy :: Proxy (ExceptT ServantErr IO)
```

The trick: Additional paramter of kind Bool!

```
class GetEndpoint api endpoint (chooseRight :: Bool)  where
  getEndpoint :: forall m. Proxy chooseRight -> Proxy m -> Proxy api -> Proxy endpoint -> ServerT api m -> ServerT endpoint m
```

Now use it to select an instance, either left:

```
-- Left choice
instance (GetEndpoint b1 endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint b1))  => GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint 'False where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint (lS :<|> _) = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy b1) pEndpoint lS
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint b1)
```

Or right, if our paramter is 'True:

```
-- Right choice
instance (GetEndpoint b2 endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint b2))  => GetEndpoint (b1 :<|> b2) endpoint 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint (_ :<|> lR) = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy b2) pEndpoint lR
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint b2)
```

Other instances - not of relevance to the original problem, but here for completeness:

```
-- Pathpiece
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (sym :> sa) (sym :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) server
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)

-- Capture
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (Capture sym a :> sa) (Capture sym1 a :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server a = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server a)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)

-- QueryParam
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (QueryParam sym a :> sa) (QueryParam sym a :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server ma = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server ma)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)

-- QueryParams
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (QueryParams sym a :> sa) (QueryParams sym a :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server as = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server as)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)

-- QueryFlag
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (QueryFlag sym :> sa) (QueryFlag sym :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server f = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server f)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)


-- Header
instance (KnownSymbol sym, GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (Header sym a :> sa) (Header sym a :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server ma = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server ma)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)


-- ReqBody
instance (GetEndpoint sa endpoint (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)) => GetEndpoint (ReqBody ct a :> sa) (ReqBody ct a :> endpoint) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ pM _ pEndpoint server a = getEndpoint pLeftRight pM (Proxy :: Proxy sa) (Proxy :: Proxy endpoint) (server a)
    where pLeftRight = Proxy :: Proxy (PickLeftRight endpoint sa)


-- Verb
instance GetEndpoint (Verb n s ct a) (Verb n s ct a) 'True where
  getEndpoint _ _ _ _ server = server


-- Raw
instance GetEndpoint Raw Raw 'True where
  getEndpoint _ _ _ _ server = server
```

Full code on [github](https://github.com/eskimor/servant-subscriber/blob/289f1a27b7d5bd3ac087fb6c51b517b4ef59d7ac/src/Lib.hs).

Thanks again for the hint user2407038!

Comment: This is a very good and complete answer! You should probably set it as accepted. As an aside, it warms my heart a tad to be thanked so many times for a tiny hint.

Comment: Well - I could not have solved this by myself - so you really saved me here ;-) Will mark as accepted - I am new to stackoverflow, did not know about that.